# Cmake compile __asm assembly inline code

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I am trying to compile `quake2` code which uses the `__asm` keyword like so:

```
__declspec( naked ) int BoxOnPlaneSide (vec3_t emins, vec3_t emaxs, 
    struct cplane_s *p)
{
    static int bops_initialized;
    static int Ljmptab[8];

    __asm {

        push ebx

        cmp bops_initialized, 1
        je  initialized
        mov bops_initialized, 1
        // more code...
```

I am using Clion which uses Cmake internally to compile. The thing is that in the code above I get the following errors

```
C:\Users\Shiro\ClionProjects\quake2\src\game\q_shared.c: In function 
'BoxOnPlaneSide':
C:\Users\Shiro\ClionProjects\quake2\src\game\q_shared.c:423:8: error: 
expected '(' before '{' token
__asm {
      ^
```

and the errors go on from there. So, how can I make this compile ? any changes to my CMakeLists.txt perhaps ? Here is part of what I have now

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Traditional -std=gnu89")
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMake or Clion directly, but with the compiler you are using. The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) doesn't use the same syntax for extensions to the language like inline assembler is. You need to use a compiler that uses the `__asm { ... }` syntax, like the Visual Studio compiler. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to do with Clion though, on the other hand you could probably use Visual Studio C++ Express (which is free) to build the source, or at least get a little further.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think you are right, I will try it and post an answer when I work this out

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude IIRC MSVC support is currently in beta, and can be enabled through the program's registry (**not** the Windows registry). See [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/03/clion-2017-1-released/#msvc).

Comment: @NicHartley Yes it's possible to use MSVC now, and the announcement was just a few days after my comment too (doh!), so it's been available for almost a year now. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup! Just figured I'd make a note for anyone else looking at this, so they could have a lead for any answers.